# getting lock wait timout when calling mysql proc from java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactions, locking

I have this below proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updatepath()
BEGIN
declare cnt, n int;
    update foo a set a.path=a.name where a.parent_id is null;
    select count(*) into cnt from foo where path is null;
    while cnt > 0 do
        update foo a, foo b set a.path = concat(b.path, '/', a.name)  where b.path is not null and a.parent_id = b.id;
        select row_count() into cnt;
    end while;
END;
;;
```

when I call this proc from mysql workbench like below:

call updatePath();
It executes successfully in few milliseconds.
But when I run the same code from a java program it takes enormous amount of time and ultimately I have to kill the java process.
COde for calling proc is as below:

```
{
            jdbcTemplate.execute(
                    new CallableStatementCreator() {
                        public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                            CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call updatePath()}");  
                            return cs;
                        }
                    },
                    new CallableStatementCallback() {
                        public Object doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs) throws SQLException {
                            cs.execute();
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
            );        
        }
```

above method is running in a separate transaction.When I kill transaction after sometime,I see that it was waiting for the lock.
On Doing **show engine innodb status**, I get below:

> ---TRANSACTION 4186138, ACTIVE 532 sec fetching rows mysql tables in use 2, locked 2 37 lock struct(s), heap size 6544, 2437 row lock(s),
>   undo log entries 307157 MySQL thread id 14, OS thread handle 0x2b38,
>   query id 461758 localhost 127.0.0.1 root Sending data
>             update foo a, foo b set a.path = concat(b.path, '/', a.name)  where b.path is not null and a.parent_id = b.id;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the "select row_count() into cnt" statement after the update in the loop.This row_count is responsible for maintaining loop.
in my case while was going in an infinite loop as update statement is always true after all the records are updated.
When I run the query on the mysql work bench separately.I see that 0 rows modified,6 rows found.While running proc from the workbench,row_count seems to be populated from the modified rows but when I ran it from the java program ,it seems to be picking up the found rows.
I got it running from both work bench and java app by modifying the query in loop to below:

```
update foo a, foo b set a.path = concat(b.path, '/', a.name)  where b.path is not null and a.parent_id = b.id **and a.path is null** ;
```